# can Apache Maven be set to download jar files from an ftp?

Tags: java, ftp, jar, maven

i want maven to download custom jar files from an ftp how to set the path?
and is there anyway i can combine dependencies or plugins within one element tag.i dont want to write for each dependency r plugin like importing from one external jars folder
btw i am using maven plugin for eclipcse ide

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to write separate elements for plugins and dependencies in you pom whether you like it or not. If you have a custom/corporate/proprietary jars, you should setup local repository somewhere on your network or elsewhere, google repository managers such as Archiva, Nexus or Artifactory or you can install those proprietary jars to your local repository.

Comment: offcourse seperate tags  for dependencies or plugins.what i mean is all the dependdencies once and all the plugins once. is it possible?

Comment: @sanre6 you have to write each dependency, however maven supports transitive dependencies so if a dependency is in need of another dependency maven will take care of it, but you will need to write primary dependencies, not transitive though. Please read some of free ebook maven by example you'll figure it out within a day.